# Will V2X communication stack become a "ASAR Platform Service"?

Tags: autosar

I'm a newbie to Autosar and I would like to understand how V2X communication stack is considered in "Adaptive Platform". Will that become a "Native platform service" (or) It shall remain as "Non Platform Service".

I could not see any related materials in autosar website.

Answer (score 1):

I think It will still be considered as an "Adaptive Platform" in the automotive ecosystem. There are a lot of stakeholders in the V2X Tech, for instance:
Chip manufacturers, Stack Providers, OEM integrators, Standart Regulators.
So, It will be really hard to become a "Native platform service"